# How to edit 'created date' from front end

Tags: joomla-3.x, form-fields-types, front-end

What file I have to change to edit the created date of an article from the front end? Using joomla 3.8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Joomla 3.x does not seem to allow the creation date to be modified from the front-end of the website.

The only third party extension I can find that enables this feature is [EasyArticles](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/authoring-a-content/content-submission/easyarticles/) which is a paid extension from StackIdeas. (You can verify this feature exists on their demo site).

There are probably other extensions that can do this and the Content Submission category in the JED might be a good place to start looking: https://extensions.joomla.org/category/authoring-a-content/content-submission

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla 3.8.3, it's possible to modify com_content > form > edit ( with override )
add in line 120 : `<?php echo $this->form->renderField('created'); ?>`

It works !

Comment: Adding that line works great.
Even in Joomla 4. Can you help to have a field label above the create date field in the front-end editting?
Now there is only a date field for the create date there.

Comment: @Wouter I have converted your non-answer to be a comment under the answer that you were attempting to speak to.  Please do not post non-answers as answers.  If you have a question that relates to this page, please post a new question, explain your situation, and include a link to this answer to give context.