# How can I enable the created date for an article to be edited in the front end?

Tags: joomla-3.x, form-fields-types, front-end

I don't know how to enable editing the created date of an article in the front-end, after updating to Joomla 3.8.10.

So far I used to override the article's edit form

**com_content -> form > edit  #line 120 :**

```
<?php echo $this->form->renderField('created'); ?>
```

as suggested in this article:
**[How to edit 'created date' from front end](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/21703/how-to-edit-created-date-from-front-end)**, and all was fine.

However, this no longer works with version 3.8.10.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

`Created` field in frontend article form contains `unset` filter. This filter prevents field value from saving. You can change the filter with a content plugin. The example below also sets `showtime` attribute to `true` in case you want to enter time like in other date fields.

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Form\Form;
use Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin;

class PlgContentExample extends CMSPlugin
{
    protected $app;

    public function onContentPrepareForm(Form $form, $data)
    {
        if ($this->app->isClient('site') && $form->getName() === 'com_content.article')
        {
            $form->setFieldAttribute('created', 'filter', 'user_utc');
            $form->setFieldAttribute('created', 'showtime', 'true');
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Note, the template override is still required to render the field.